# Transferring the registration of an iPhone

Tags: iphone

I currently own an iPhone 4s and would like to gift it to a friend. It is currently registered to me but i want to register it to his name so that I don't have to involve myself in warranty issues or repair issues. How is it possible to transfer the registration to another person?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so but visiting this link here:
[My Support Profile](https://supportprofile.apple.com/MySupportProfile.do)

After you login with your registered Apple ID, you can see all your registered devices. Click on the device and "unregister".

Once that is complete, your friend can do the same to register it under his/her Apple ID.